# PHP session mode keeps using 0600 permissions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have been trying to change the permissions of new session files. According to [this page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path), I need to change the *mode* in the session_save_path configuration in the php.ini file. I have changed it to 0777, the default is 0600. New session files are still being created with 0600 permissions. I have checked, the correct php.ini is loaded and the changes are saved. I have configured it like: `0;0777;/var/lib/php/sessions` (N;MODE;/path). Can someone explain to me why the files are still created with 0600 permissions, while I have configured it to 0777?

The files are stored in `/var/lib/php/sessions` and I'm using Codeigniter.

Comment: Could it be that you also have to change the process' umask, since that affects _all_ files created by a process?

Comment: Are you restart apache after change php.ini?

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев Yes I restarted apache

Comment: @arkascha That's not an answer to my question. I have tried multiple different permissions just for the sake of testing if it works.

Comment: I never claimed that this comment is an answer to your question. That is why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer. On SO one posts comments to point out strange details of things the OP most likely has overlooked or not really understood.

Comment: Interesting, my first comment was deleted without my knowledge. And without me getting informed. I wonder how that is possible, the only way I know of is that a moderator can delete comments. But why would one want to do that?

Comment: @arkascha i see your first comment

Comment: @Alex I made two comments as first comments to the question. Only one of those is currently visible to me: "Could it be..." The one before that is missing "Why would one..."

Comment: weird. maybe you deleted by accident or someone modded it by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/var/lib/php/sessions/` directory typically has the "sticky" bit set on it -

```
drwx-wx-wt 2 root root 4096 Oct 15 11:21 /var/lib/php/sessions/
```

This is done via `chmod 1733`.  Remember that using the setuid/setgid/sticky bits on a directory effect how files are created (default owner/group and permissions) in that directory and any sub-directory, regardless of system `umask` values, etc.

From this page - http://www.filepermissions.com/articles/sticky-bit-suid-and-sgid - which is part of a 3 article series on *nix file permissions which is pretty good.

> A Sticky Bit, is a special setting within file permissions that helps
>   limit access beyond what normal file permissions are capable of. In
>   short, a Sticky Bit ensures only the owner of the file / directory is
>   able to delete or rename the file. However it should be noted that
>   root is able to edit and delete the file as well.

With the mode of `1733` the session data files can't be read by others on the system.  This is a Good Thing.

Why do you want world readable session storage?

**Edit -**

If you really want to break it, create a new directory w/ appropriate permissions and change the session storage path to use that directory.  Note that there may be an internal check in PHP that will make it refuse to store session data in a place it considers "insecure", much like SSH refusing to use keys w/ insecure permissions.

Comment: I need to be able to read the session files from a PHP file, thats why I need it to be readable. Thanks for the answer, I will try it.

Comment: So I get the idea that its kinda stupid making this world readable. Why is that so? If I am the only user on the system and there's just people visiting my website, what is the problem of the directory being world readable?

Comment: @P.Yntema the idea behind security is that it is a multilayered approach.  You lock stuff down on the file system because one day you might not be the only user on the system.